# RangeError: radix must be an integer at least 2 and no greater than 36

Tags: javascript, jsp, datejs

When I try and convert milliseconds to a string I get an error saying

> RangeError: radix must be an integer at least 2 and no greater than 36

I am using the Datejs script and using the toString function.

```
var date2 = (returnDay + time);
alert("Return Date is:"+ date2.toString("MMM-dd-yy"));
```

The return day is todays date

```
var returnDate = new Date().getTime();
```

and the time is the answer. It is all in milliseconds.

```
time=14*24*60*60*1000
```

When I go to convert the milliseconds to a String I get the error
Can anyone help?

Comment: where are you defining returnDay? In you new date declaration you have the variable called "returnDate" and not "returnDay". Could that be the issue?
This works for me: new Date().getTime().toString();

Comment: var date = new Date().getTime();
    var returnDay = new Date(date); @dudewad

Comment: I figure it out thanks a lot @dudewad

Comment: Be aware that [Datejs is abandoned](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).